# FMX.Platform.Android.pas from Delphi XE10.2 Tokyo vs from Delphi XE10.3 Rio

Tags: android, delphi

In TMS component using this snap code :

```
FMX.Platform.Android.MainActivity.getTextEditorProxy.setText(AText:JCharSequence);
FMX.Platform.Android.MainActivity.getTextEditorProxy.setCursorPosition(ACaretPosition:TPoint);
```

I have succeeded compile in Delphi XE10.2, but I get error when to try compile in Delphi XE10.3 :

```
[DCC Error] FMX.TMSRichEditor.pas(901): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'getTextEditorProxy'
```

I try to look into FMX.Platform.Android and found a function '**function MainActivity: JFMXNativeActivity**', but I didn't found **getTextEditorProxy** in  interface object **JFMXNativeActivity**.

My question is:

How to fix this error or is there a program code to replace the old program code above that has changed in the FMX.Platform.Android.pas file on the Delphi XE10.3 ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can only ask TMS to redraw their components as 10.3 Rio change completely their FMX.Platform.Android.pas

Comment: I think this is not just a TMS component that uses the FMX.Platform.Android.pas from Embarcadero file where the function of the 'MainActivity: JFMXNativeActivity' function differs between the Delphi XE10.2 version and Delphi XE10.3. It could be that other components not from TMS also use it. So I asked how to modify the use of the 'MainActivity: JFMXNativeActivity' function according to the Delphi XE10.3 version to avoid FMX.TMSRichEditor.pas (901) error : [DCC Error]: E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'getTextEditorProxy'.

Comment: Did you manage to find anything relating on how to solve this problem?

Comment: use FMX.Platform.Android.MainActivity.getEditText;